# .dockerignore exclude certain subfolders

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a node_modules folder that includes two private packages under `/node_modules/@mymodules/schema` and `/node_modules/@mymodules/ui`. Running `npm install` fails in my Dockerfile once it tries to install those packages, as expected.

I want to exclude those folders from .dockerignore, but I do not know why the following is not working:

```
node_modules/**/*
!node_modules/@mymodules/**/*
```

If I `exec bash` into the container and `ls` it shows that the `!` exclusion didn't do anything`. How can I exclude node_modules but include those modules?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: Hi @ForTheWin, I just tested this out and it's working as expected. There must have been some other entry in the file or something. To test, I made a Dockerfile like this: `FROM alpine ; COPY . . ; RUN find . ` (pretend the ; is a newline) and when you build with `docker build -t dockerignore:test .` it will show the files. I used the .dockerignore listed above, and it worked: it only included node_modules/@mymodules/ and it indeed excluded node_modules/otherfolder/. My filesystem for testing: https://imgur.com/a/Y9lCrh3

Comment: thank you @swagrov -- I'll see if I can do something similar